# What are the names of these types of cables?

Tags: identification

I need the name for these cable connectors, for use in a user manual

[image]

The flexible part has 4 lines and connects to hearing aids.

[image]

The smaller end has 4 holes and connects to the end with the label **CS 64** of the cable in the first figure. The larger end looks like a male 6 pin PS/2 connector. Both cables are required for programming hearing aid through I2C bus.

What are the names for these cables?

EDIT1: Close up of the flexible cable attached to a hearing aid

[image]

Comment: The red one is DIN. Please take close ups of the others.

Comment: @winny added closeup of the flexible cable

Comment: I'd call them "hearing aid programming cables", and they may proprietary to a specific hearing aid manufacturer.  I doubt if there is any "generic" name for those cables.

Comment: The flat one is an FFC or Flat Flexible Cable (or Flat Flexible  Conductor), so your own description is very close.